# mysql - "UNLOCK TABLES" hangs frequently. What could be the reason?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I am using pymyql to connect to my DB and perform some actions.

```
def clean_tokens():
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='mysql', port=3306, user='root', passwd='pass', db='tokens', read_timeout=3, write_timeout=3)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute("LOCK TABLES tokens WRITE")
        cursor.execute("select user_uuid,username,session_id from tokens where expiration_time < NOW() ")
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        expired_token_query = "DELETE FROM tokens WHERE expiration_time < NOW() "
        tokens_deleted = cursor.execute(expired_token_query)
        cursor.execute("UNLOCK TABLES")
        
        if results:
            cursor.execute("LOCK TABLES lasttokendetail WRITE")
            for result in results:
                user_uuid = result[0]
                username = result[1]
                session_id = result[2]
                cursor.execute("update lasttokendetail set lasttokendetail.modifiedTime=now() where user_uuid='%s'" % user_uuid)
            cursor.execute("UNLOCK TABLES")
    except Exception as e:
        log.info("Failed to removed dead tokens %s", e)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
```

This runs every 30 minutes in the system. But once in a while this starts to throw exception.
`OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query (timed out)'`

`show full processlist \G;` shows that connection is stuck at `UNLOCK TABLES`

```
*************************** 2. row ***************************
      Id: 2
    User: system user
    Host: 
      db: NULL
 Command: Sleep
    Time: 8532
   State: Waiting for table metadata lock
    Info: NULL
Progress: 0.000
*************************** 4. row ***************************
      Id: 585904
    User: root
    Host: 172.16.0.9:39895
      db: tokens
 Command: Query
    Time: 8532
   State: init
    Info: UNLOCK TABLES
Progress: 0.000
```

I am wondering what could cause `UNLOCK TABLES` to hang as it can do commit by itself too.

Comment: Why do you need to lock tables every 30 minutes in the first place?

Comment: This is just a support process. Want to make sure that it takes lock and performs operation without interfering with django based application.

Comment: Innodb tables can do row level locks, so you do not need to use table level ones.

Comment: yes, will change to row lock. Thanks for valuable input. But still wondering what could cause UNLOCK TABLES to hang? If a process has lock, it should be able to unlock, right? Under what circumstances can this hang?

Comment: It is not necessarily hung. As you mentioned, it causes an implicit commit. If you do not have autocommit enabled, that means all the  changes you have done are committed with the unlock tables and mysql may run out of time.

Comment: `"The correct way to use LOCK TABLES and UNLOCK TABLES with transactional tables, such as InnoDB tables, is to begin a transaction with SET autocommit = 0 (not START TRANSACTION) followed by LOCK TABLES, and to not call UNLOCK TABLES until you commit the transaction explicitly."` source:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html#lock-tables-and-transactions

Comment: Thanks. And if I lock rows only `cursor.execute("select user_uuid,username,session_id from tokens where expiration_time < NOW() FOR UPDATE")`, is `cursor.execute("FLUSH TABLE tokens ")` is correct way to unlock the rows? Also, setting autocommit to 0 won't be required in this case?

Comment: Nope. I would start the transaction before issuing the locking select do all updates and deletes and then commit the transaction. The commit will release all locks acquired by the transaction.